# Angular 9 CDK Portal Error: Must provide a portal to attach

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk

I am having a difficult time with something that seems pretty straightforward. I am trying to open a new window with some html in angular 9. Everytime it runs, I see a window popup for a second, before it fails and throws the following error:

```
Error: Must provide a portal to attach
    at throwNullPortalError (portal.js:23)
    at DomPortalHost.attach (portal.js:320)
    at GraphPopoutComponent.ngOnInit (graph-popout.component.ts:43)
    at callHook (core.js:4686)
    at callHooks (core.js:4650)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.js:4591)
    at refreshView (core.js:11814)
    at refreshDynamicEmbeddedViews (core.js:13154)
    at refreshView (core.js:11819)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:13229)
```

Before anyone asks:

- yes, I have included PortalModule in my app.module.ts
- angular 9.0.7
- angular/cdk, angular/material 9.1.3
- i do have nested modules, would that cause an issue with the PortalModule?

Here is my code for reference:

> graph.component.html

```
.
.
.
<app-graph-popout *ngIf="openPortal">
  <h1>IT WORKS</h1>
</app-graph-popout>
```

> graph.component.ts

```
.
.
.
togglePortal() {
    this.openPortal = true;
  }
```

> graph-popout.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-graph-popout',
  // templateUrl: './graph-popout.component.html',
  template: `
    <ng-container *cdkPortal>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </ng-container>
  `


})
export class GraphPopoutComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  // STEP 1: get a reference to the portal
  @ViewChild(CdkPortal) portal: CdkPortal;

  // STEP 2: save a reference to the window so we can close it
  private externalWindow = null;

  // STEP 3: Inject all the required dependencies for a PortalHost
  constructor(
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private applicationRef: ApplicationRef,
    private injector: Injector) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // STEP 4: create an external window
    this.externalWindow = window.open('', '', 'width=600,height=400,left=200,top=200');

    // STEP 5: create a PortalHost with the body of the new window document
    const host = new DomPortalHost(
      this.externalWindow.document.body,
      this.componentFactoryResolver,
      this.applicationRef,
      this.injector
    );

    // STEP 6: Attach the portal
    host.attach(this.portal);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    // STEP 7: close the window when this component destroyed
    this.externalWindow.close();
  }

}
```

Comment: Why you want open a new window with the content? I don't know if that works with window.open because the new window doesn't have reference to your angular app. I'm supposing. Maybe is better to use a modal instead an empty window.open

Comment: @AlanGrosz It needs to be in a separate window, not a modal so that I can move the window to another screen while still using the app on the original screen. Is there a way to give it a reference to my angular app?

Answer (score 5):

Faced the same problem. Following the example @[angular doc](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) moved the code block from ngOnInit to ngAfterViewInit which solved this problem.

Modified working sample @[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-open-window-bvenwh) uses angular 10.0.3

Answer (score 0):

I found a stackblitz that maybe can help you
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-open-window.

Obviously it can. I just learned something new :P